# Removing TYPO3 loading page

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I don't know TYPO3 very well yet and created my first page. Every time I call up my page or change the page in the navigation, a blue TYPO3 page appears.  Does anyone know this problem and know how to remove this page?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you send an image of the blue page?

Comment: @Shotokan I can't take a screenshot of the blue site because it is only visible for 1 second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean the Preloader from the Bootstrap Package Extension?

You can change the Logo and Background Color in the [Typo3 Constant Editor](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/UsingSetting/TheConstantEditor.html) in the category "BOOTSTRAP PACKAGE: PRELOADER (6)".

Comment: Hello Thomas, Sorry, I don't know much about Typo3 yet. Right, the Preloder.
I try it now.